# カラムの文字コードを確認したい。show create table (テーブル名);結果で文字コード指定されていないカラムの文字コードは何ですか？

Tags: mysql

MySQLでカラムの文字コードを確認したい。
「show create table (テーブル名);」を実行した際、カラムの文字コード指定していないカラムの文字コードを確認する方法を知りたい。

＜ 経緯 ＞
・MySQLで絵文字がINSERTできないカラム(`body`)がありました。
・カラムの文字コードを確認しようと show create table (テーブル名);を実行しましたが、`body`カラムには文字コード指定されていませんでした。

＜ 試した内容 ＞
show create `status`;
CREATE TABLE `status` (
`topic_description` varchar(1000) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT '',
`body` text NOT NULL,

・この場合、`body`カラムの文字コードは何になりますか？
・現状の文字コード設定は下記ですが、「character_set_system」だけがutf8になっている理由など、あまりよく理解できていません。

```
mysql> show variables like 'char%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
```

環境
MySQL5.7

Comment: テーブルやデータベース単位でも文字コードは指定できます。該当のテーブルやデータベースには`CHARACTER SET`で何かセットされていますか？

Comment: 解決しました。ありがとうございます。テーブルの文字コード設定がutf8になっていたことが原因でした。テーブルにも文字コード設定されていることを今回初めて知りました……。